# Is max of outer measure also an outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, outer-measure

Take $\mu^*_1,\mu^*_2$ be an outer measures on X, then prove that
$$\nu^*(A)=\max\{ \mu^*_1(A),\mu^*_2(A) \},~A\in2^X$$ is an outer measure.

Let's remind definition of outer measure.

> Let $X$ be any (non-empty) set.  A function $\nu \colon X \longrightarrow [0,\infty]$ is an *outer measure* if

> 1. $$ \nu^*(\emptyset)=0. $$

> 2. $$ \nu^*(A) \leq \nu^*(B)$$ whenever  $A\subseteq B \subseteq X$.

> 3. $$ \nu^* \left( \cup_{n=1}^\infty  A_n \right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\nu^* \left( A_n \right) $$
>    for any sequence $\left( A_n \right)_{n=1}^\infty$ of subsets of $X$.

Proof:

> Step $0$: Take $A\subset X$. Then
> $$ \nu^*(A)= \max \left\{ \mu_1^*(A),\mu_2^* (A) \right\} \in [0, \infty] $$
> because both $\mu_1^*(A)$ and $\mu_2^* (A)$ are in $[0, \infty]$.

> Step $1$: $$ \nu^*(\emptyset)= \max \left\{ \mu_1^*(\emptyset),\mu_2^* (\emptyset) \right\}=0 $$
> because $\mu_1^*(\emptyset)=0 = \mu_2^*(\emptyset) $.

> Step $2$: Let $A$ and $B$ be any subsets of $X$ such that  $A\subseteq B$. Let us assume without any loss of generality that $ \mu_1^* (A) \leq \mu_2^* (A)$. Then
> $$
> \begin{align}
>  \nu^*(A) &= \max \left\{ \mu_1^* (A), \mu_2^* (A) \right\} \\ 
> &= \mu_2^*(A) \\
> &\leq \mu_2^* (B) \\ 
> &\leq \max \left\{ \mu_1^* (B), \mu_2^* (B) \right\} \\ 
> &= \nu^*(B)
> \end{align}
> $$

> Step $3$: Let $\left( A_n \right)_{n=1}^\infty$ be any sequence of subsets of $X$. Let us assume without any loss of generality that
> $$ \mu_1^* \left( \cup_{n=1}^\infty  A_n \right) \leq \mu_2^* \left( \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right). $$
> Then
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> \nu^* \left( \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) &= \max \left\{ \mu_1^* \left( \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right), \mu_2^* \left( \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) \right\} \\ 
> &= \mu_2^* \left( \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) \\
> &\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_2^* \left(A_n \right) \\
> &\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \max \left\{ \mu_1^* \left(A_n\right), \mu_2^* \left(A_n\right) \right\} \\ 
> &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu^* \left(A_n\right). 
> \end{align}
> $$

> $\square$

Should I correct something in my proof?